# vscode azure app configuration 403 forbidden

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-app-configuration, azure-identity

I'm developing a c# azure function app using vscode on mac. I have the Azure extension installed and I've used it to login to azure.

I have an integration test that attempts to read from an app configuration as follows:

```cs
string endpoint = "https://<myappconfigendpoint>.azconfig.io";
var client = new ConfigurationClient(new Uri(endpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential());

string settingKey = "func-amx-api:TimeOfLastPoll";
ConfigurationSetting settingRead = client.GetConfigurationSetting(settingKey);
```

This line containing "client.GetConfigurationSetting" fails with a 403 forbidden error.

Using ProxyMan (like Fiddler) I've copied the bearer token that gets presented to the app configuration endpoint. I pasted this into https://jwt.ms and confirmed that the "aud" and "upn" values look to be correct. The aud contains the app configuration endpoint and the upn is my user principal - which has a role assignment of "App Configuration Data Owner" over the app configuration.

My test project contains the following nuget packages:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.AppConfiguration" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.9.0" />
```

Comment: Have you checked the "oid" claim matches your user's object ID? Also check the "tid" claim matches the Azure AD tenant ID. One thing that can happen is that it gets an access token for the wrong Azure AD tenant, resulting in the wrong tid and oid values.

Comment: not so sure about it, here's the [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process) for a function. As you can see this used a connection string. And in your code snippet, you used DefaultAzureCredential, so maybe a publishment can help to test if the identity you used is environment variable/[managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?pivots=framework-dotnet&tabs=core5x).

Comment: DefaultAzureCredential:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential

Comment: @juunas I can confirm oid and tid claims match expected values when I view them in the azure portal

Answer (score 1):

This must have been a timing issue. Perhaps there was a delay after me making the role assignment for my account again the the app configuration.

I ran the same code after lunch and it worked!